# WCF Faulted State

Tags: c#, wcf

How can a WCF `CommunicationObject` transition to a faulted state: I created a WCF library in Visual Studio, deployed it into IIS, inside it i have two methods:

```
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        throw new FaultException(value.ToString());
    }

    public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
    {
        throw new TestException();
    }
```

From the client, i simply call these two methods over and over again, however, the `CommunicationObjectFaultedException` is not thrown at any time.

I read in an article [WCF error handling and some best practices](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pedram/archive/2008/01/25/wcf-error-handling-and-some-best-practices.aspx) that non-FaultExceptions are converted by default "automatically" to a FaultException. If this is right, then when and how does the WCF client's communication object become in a faulted state?

One other thing, does anybody know any MSDN reference that confirms that `FaultException` is the best way to make sure the WCF communication object does not transition into `Faulted state`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The channel will be on a faulted state if you are using a session (i.e. a binding that supports session) and a call to a method raises an exception that is not handled.

Another way you can get into a faulted state is the session timing out while the channel is open.

It is the *channel* that is in a faulted state, not the service

[Understanding State Changes in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789041%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)